# How do I hard-code a type into my models in Django

Tags: database, django, django-models, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

Here's the logic for the models:

1. Category. There are several categories; each category can contain several products.
2. Product. There are several products; each product can only have one category.

Is it possible to specify what kind of category each product is within the model file itself? For example: can I set the model so that a `shirt` can only be `clothing` and nothing else?

Here's what I have so far (it doesn't validate):

```
class Category(models.Model):
   CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('CLOTHING', 'Clothing'),
        ('FURNITURE', 'Furniture'),
   )
   category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)


class Shirt(Product):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=CATEGORY_CHOICES.CLOTHING)

    class Table(Product):
       category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=CATEGORY_CHOICES.FURNITURE)
```

I'm new at this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This level of validation should be done in code.

Comment: I agree with @Sid, hardcoding this kind of stuff will get over complex and is not very slick design, this belongs in model, possibly form validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate your model on save with any arbitrary rules.  So, write a validation rule that checks that all shirts are saved in the category clothing.

For user input, create a form that only provides choices corresponding to the product.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the input! Quick clarification question: is it necessary to have a Category class at all then? Or can i definite a method such as def category(self) that specifies what the category can be for that specific model?

Comment: Seems like you need to define allowed product categories somewhere if you are going to validate them.  If I was doing it, I would create a method that returns allowed categories for a given product and populate a choice field in the displayed form with it.  I'd probably do the validation as a check as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you invest some time into adopting recently added [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), while it's not automatic as forms validation (you'll have to call `clean*` methods yourself, probably inside `save`), you gonna get DRY validation that could be used on Model and Form level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callables to give instance as a default value

Something like this (untested code):

```
class Shirt(Product):

  def getClothingInstance():
    return Category.objects.get(category=Category.CATEGORY_CHOISES['CLOTHING'])

  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=getClothingInstance)
```